# RobotFramework | Choose File | Angular | Not working

Tags: angular, robotframework, filedialog

I cannot figure out how to use the "Choose File" functionality

I have the following website in which i want to upload the file C://RobotAutomation/Customers/in/test.csv

The website looks as follows

[image]

The corresponding html is as follows:

[image]

My Test Script in RobotFramework is as follows:

```
Click Button   xpath=//button[@name='file']
Sleep 5
Choose File  xpath=//button[@name='file']  C://RobotAutomation/Customers/in/test.csv
```

The result is that the File Dialog box is opened, but it is not automatically populated with the test.csv file.

I am not sure if the correct locator is specified. This is because of the Angular code that is used.

What i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please take the time to add the html as text to the question - not a picture link; format the code properly (use either 4 spaces before each line, or ``` for start & end of the code block); and preferably embed the image so it displays inline. In its current form, it's really hard to read - and not a lot of folks are going to type out the html just to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

If that file name is the actual value you use in the script, it is not correct - Windows does support `/` as path separator, but you have 2 between "C:" and "RobotAutomation".
Try like this:

```
Choose File  xpath=//button[@name='file']  C:/RobotAutomation/Customers/in/test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, works for me C:\\RobotAutomation\\Customers\\in\\test.csv